# Passing in variables with Laravel Mix and PostCSS

Tags: laravel-mix, postcss

I have a project using Laravel Mix and Sass where I can pass in variables to be used in the `scss` files like this:

```
.sass('app/styles/app.scss', `${distPath}/app.css`, {
    includePaths: ['node_modules'],
    data: (process.env.PREVIEW) ? '$theme: themename-preview;' : '$theme: themename;'
})
```

and then in the `scss`, I can do `background-image: url(/themes/#{$theme}/images/…)`

Now I want to do the same thing with another project using PostCSS which is set up like this:

```
mix.postCss('app/styles/app.css', 'dist', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss')
]);
```

I've looked at a couple of different PostCSS plugins like `postcss-simple-vars` and `postcss-themed` but must not be configuring them correctly because I always get `$theme` printed in the output.

Does anyone have any recommendations with examples of how to do this?

Comment: In Laravel Mix with PostCSS, you can pass variables to your CSS files using the postcss-custom-properties plugin. https://github.com/postcss/postcss-custom-properties

Comment: @KarlHill Thanks, hadn't come across this one, will check it out.